# Flexibility vs performance considered good practice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not stuck with my code because I don't know how to write it but more because I'm split between two ways of doing and don't know which path to go.

I will first write my problem then post some code.

So I have a switch with 4 cases and then in my function called by the cases, I have two more cases (ifs). I have to rewrite the code used in all those cases but a little different in every one.

If I write all the code, I have less things to check therefor it's more performant but it makes the code less flexible.

```
 private void FillDiagonalStartAndEnd(FastNoise noiseBiome, FastNoise noiseTransition)
{
    switch (direction)
    {
        case DirectionOfBiomeCell.NE:
            TransitionDiagonallyNorthEast(noiseBiome, noiseTransition); // Less checks
            break;
        case DirectionOfBiomeCell.SE:
            towardsRight = 1;
            TransitionDiagonallyED(noiseBiome, noiseTransition, new Vector2(spacePosX -1, spacePosZ + BIOME_CELL_SIZE), new Vector2(spacePosX + BIOME_CELL_SIZE - 1, spacePosZ)); // More flexible
            break;
        case DirectionOfBiomeCell.SW:
            //TransitionLinearlySouth(noiseBiome, noiseTransition);
            break;
        case DirectionOfBiomeCell.NW:
            //TransitionLinearlyWest(noiseBiome, noiseTransition);
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Log("Default case in FillDiagonallyStartAndEnd");
            break;
    }
}
```

Above, I have the NE direction which is more performant I think and then SE direction which is flexible with parameters.

Then in the functions :

```
private void TransitionDiagonallyED(FastNoise noiseBiome, FastNoise noiseTransition, Vector2 start, Vector2 end)
{
    //Variables for flexible function
    int heightModificator;

    //Start and ending values for diagonal line
    int startValue = TerrainGen.GetNoise2D(noiseBiome, (int)start.x, (int)start.y, TerrainGen.min, TerrainGen.max);
    int endValue = TerrainGen.GetNoise2D(noiseTransition, (int)end.x, (int)end.y, TerrainGen.min, TerrainGen.max);

    //Step values
    float endMinusStart = endValue - startValue;
    float stepValue = endMinusStart / BIOME_CELL_SIZE;

    //1 or 0 for height start of diagonal
    heightModificator = (int)start.y > spacePosX ? 1 : 0;

    for (int xz = 0; xz < BIOME_CELL_SIZE; xz++)
    {
        //Making diagonal and adjusting if it starts at the bottom or top of the square
        transitionHeights[xz, Mathf.Abs((BIOME_CELL_SIZE - 1) * heightModificator - xz)] = Mathf.RoundToInt((startValue + stepValue * (xz + 1)) * towardsRight + (endValue - xz * stepValue) * towardsLeft);
    }
}
```

I won't post all of the other function since it's very long but above you can see in the loop that I am using multiplication by 0 or 1. This is set in the heightModificator which doesn't exist in the other function with no parameters. This is very handy since it's flexible and set in the beginning of the class.

```
public int towardsRight = 0;
public int towardsLeft = 0;
```

Now the other function doesn't need this since it's only usable in the case the direction is NE

```
private void TransitionDiagonallyNorthEast(FastNoise noiseBiome, FastNoise noiseTransition)
{
    float endMinusStart;
    float stepValue;

    if (position == PositionOfBiomeCell.outward)
    {
        //For diagonal
        endMinusStart = valuesFromTransitionNoiseEND[BIOME_CELL_SIZE - 1] - valuesFromBiomeNoiseSTART[0];
        stepValue = endMinusStart / BIOME_CELL_SIZE;

        for (int xz = 0; xz < BIOME_CELL_SIZE; xz++)
        {
            //Filling diagonal
            transitionHeights[xz, xz] = Mathf.RoundToInt(valuesFromBiomeNoiseSTART[0] + (xz + 1) * stepValue);
```

So, above you can see there is no multiplication by heightModificator. The functions aren't finished, so there would be two more loops of this kind in both of the function. I didn't want to write them since I don't know for which one to go. What is considered good practice, being more flexible but less performant or the opposite?

In my case this code will be executed **A LOT** of times. I would say in my Start() function about 2080 (because a lot of objects use this code). Furthermore, my two loops which loop around 496 times each will be nested in the first one.

Thanks for reading

Best regards.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Use the flexible method. I doubt the "less performant" method is actually less performant. Try to optimize only when you _need_ to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is considered good practice, being more flexible but less performant or the opposite?

Until you are sure there is a performance issue, don't look for a way to optimize it. There is a good chance that you're spending time on the wrong thing. For your example, a decent device won't even break a sweat with simple code like this being called 2000 times, even if you do the these calls every second.

On the other hand, having clean code will enable you to work faster and produce less bugs. And it's easier to optimize clean code to make it faster than to clean up unnecessary optimizations.